# My image icon refuses to align center or shift in anyway inside an anchor tag

Tags: html, css, image, anchor, vertical-alignment

The following  is the code for the nav inside my header. The image refuses to budge whatever i try. i need the image to vertically align with the text in the buttons next to it. 
I've tried display:table-cell but maybe i placed it wrongly.

```
<nav id="headerNav">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href = "#" id="logoLink" style="padding-top:15px">
            <img src="images/Logo.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href = "#" id="logoHeader" style="padding-left:0px; margin-right:15%;">
            Something
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS :-

```
#headerNav
{
margin-top:2%;
margin-bottom:1%;
padding-bottom:2%;


}
header nav ul {

margin:1em 0;
padding:0;
width:100%;

}

header nav ul li
{
display:inline;
list-style-type:none;

}
header nav ul li a img
{
    width:auto;
height:auto;
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;

}

header nav ul li a {

 font-family:'OpenSansReg', sans-serif;
color:#4D4D4D;
font-size:1.0em;
font-weight:400;
padding:1.7%;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:white;


}
```

Comment: This should really be a background image and then you would have no problems aligning it. JSfiddle required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check updating your html/css code as mentioned below:

1. remove inline style for padding-top from `<a href = "#" id="logoLink" style="padding-top:15px">` and make it like: `<a href = "#" id="logoLink">`
2. add following css properties to your `#headerNav ul li a` (in your code above it mentioned as `header nav ul li a`) class:

   `display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;`

Hope it will help you!

Comment: glad as its helped you! Could you please select this as answer to your question by clicking the right-tick just below to arrows on left.